# Function call for each element of a list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I came across some code in python which I am unable to understand completely.

```
[func([t.string]) for t in textList]
```

where textList is a list of html tag enclosed text. What it does and how is it different from this?

```
for t in textList
    func(t.string)
```

Comment: The list comprehension results in a new list with the return values of each `func()` call.

Comment: So, disregarding the return value, does both the syntaxes return in the similar function call?

Comment: You can't disregard the return value, that's the *whole point* of the list comprehension. Your own loop version doesn't pass in a list with one element, you'd have to call `func([t.string])` like the original.

Comment: To fully reproduce what the list comprehension syntax does you'd need to add a line above your loop: `result = []`, then use `result.append(func([t.string]))` as your loop body. `result` would then end up being the same list as what the list comprehension produces.